# Cannot understand what create adapter is Sailsjs expecting

Tags: node.js, sails.js, custom-adapter

Whenever I try to execute the below code using POSTMAN, it shows me an error.

I even tried adding the create adapter by using "let create user = await User.create etc.." but it is still showing error.

*Code*

```
//Controller file content

module.exports = {

  register: function(req, res){
    data = {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      description: req.body.description
    };
    console.log(data);
    User.create(data)
    .fetch()
    .exec((err) => {
      if(err){return res.serverError(err);}
    });
  }
```

[image: I even tried adding the create adapter by using "let create user = await User.create etc.." but it is still showing error.]

I don't understand if the code is wrong or maybe I am missing something. Please help.

Comment: I suspect you need to return the created user when the create is successful via one of the `res` methods - you should be able to get the created model from one of the params of your `exec` callback. After that, maybe something like `return res.send(user);`

Comment: Can you add your custom-adapter? That's where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```js
register: function(req, res){
    data = {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      description: req.body.description
    };
    console.log(data);
    User.create(data)
    .exec((err, user) => {
      if(err){return res.serverError(err);}
      else {res.send(user)}
    });
  }
```

Or:

```js
register: async function(req, res){
    data = {
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      description: req.body.description
    };
    console.log(data);
    const user = await User.create(data)
    .intercept(err => new Error(err))
    .fetch();

    return res.send(user);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first solution and its working now.